# Magento - Parse widget/cms declarations from static block

Tags: magento, content-management-system

Consider a standard Magento block that loads in the content of a static block. If I want to parse out any widget (or for that matter, any other CMS declarations) out of that block, will it be necessary to construct a method that does standard preg_match type of operations to parse these strings or am I able to use built-in methods to grab each declaration and add it to my own array/object?

Looking at the 'widget/template_filter' class that handles normal parsing of these declarations, the only method up the chain I can find that may prove useful is the protected _getIncludeParameters() method in Varien/Template.php.

It's rather late, so I imagine I will update this question tomorrow with additional details.

--edit--

Err... reading this following day, and I certainly worded this poorly. I blame my girlfriend.

A better way to phrase this would be...

Consider the following static block:

```
<?php $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('my_static_block') ?>
<?php $content = $block->getContent() ?>
```

$content will give me the unparsed content with cms/widget declarations still intact, such as:

```
{{widget type="my/widget" template="my/template.phtml"}}
```

Now I simply want to convert this declaration back into an object (or more appropriately, I will have several {{widget}} declarations that I want to drop into an array) so that I can check param values, do other work, etc, such as:

```
<?php foreach ($content->getWidgets() as $widget) : ?>
    <?php echo $widget->getValue() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I load blocks with raw value or parsed value:

```
/**
 * Implement function getStaticBlock().
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getStaticBlock($blockName) {
    // get the content of the block
    $content=array();
    if (!empty($blockName)) $content=Mage::getModel('cms/block')
        ->load($blockName)
        ->getContent();

    return array($content);
}

/**
 * Implement function getRenderedBlock().
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getRenderedBlock($blockName) {
    // get the content of the block
    $content=array();
    if (!empty($blockName)) $content=Mage::app()
        ->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('cms/block')
        ->setBlockId($blockName)
        ->toHtml();

    return array($content);
}
```